# Youtube videos not working on mobile

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have some youtube videos on my site. They works fine on desktop(and also when i resize the desktop browser screen to mobile screen size). But when i try to view those videos on mobile, the youtube app opens and the videos are played in the app and not on the website. I want the video to be played on the site itself and not in an app. Is there any solution for this?

HTML:

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/xyz&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;fs=1?rel=0&amp;border=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="370"></embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to using `iframe` instead of `embed`. See [Youtube iFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

> The IFrame player API lets you embed a YouTube video player on your website and control the player using JavaScript. Unlike the Flash and JavaScript player APIs, which both involve embedding a Flash object on your web page, the IFrame API posts content to an `<iframe>` tag on your page

Here's an example on how to use `iframe`:

```
<iframe title="YouTube" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src=YOUTUBE_VIDEO frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```